# CSV or JSON file from List

Tags: java, android, sql, json, list

So, I have populated a List from an internally stored SQLite table. I would like to send this list to a web service. Can I send the list itself or should I store it in a JSONarray or CSV file? Is there an easy way of converting the List to either of these. Please provide some sample code as I am having trouble coming up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of following standards, I believe you should definitely use JSON. If its a list, its very easy to construct the JSON with simple string concatenation.

I imagine the JSON would look like

```
{ col1:"Value1", col2:"Value2", col3:"Value3" }
```

Comment: used JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(sqlist); I didnt realize I could just pass the list in.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON, You could try the Gson library for ease of conversion. The Jackson library might be more efficient. Since you asked for an example, the following is a snippet from the [Gson page](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Collections Examples

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Collection<Integer> ints = Lists.immutableList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

(Serialization)

```
String json = gson.toJson(ints); ==> json is [1,2,3,4,5]
```

(Deserialization)

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Otherwise have a look at protobufs - probably more efficient.

On android you might have issues with Gson speeds in certain situations but it should work

Comment: Can you provide some example of Protocol Buffers use?

Comment: search for phonelist here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

Comment: I have spend 3 days here, could not get it, any tutorials.

Comment: sure, I thought you may have some working example. Thanks anyway.